# How to preserve the workflow state on closing a custom modal in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: pipelines, workflow, events, sheer-ui

My Customer has a regulatory compliance requirement to add secondary authentication prior to any workflow approval, so the approach that I have taken is by defining a custom Action which opens a DialogForm and it handles the authentication part.

It works great, but there is one problem where the state of the workflow changes automatically to the next state when a modal is closed before a user is authenticated.

For example, if a workflow has 3 states (Draft -> Submit (If this has that authentication requirement, then the user has to get stuck in the same state until the user authenticates) -> Approve)

I know the existing out of the box Approve action is handling this scenario but I was not able to track the right dll to see the code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We had the similar requirement where we open up a pop-up and based on the response from user move it to "Approved" or "Draft". We set the Next State for the command as current state and added a custom action which decides where the flow needs to be re-directed.

Comment: @Gobinath Interesting approach, but If we do it that way then we lose out of the box functionality of the processor like adding the history which I know will be and there might be something else that the processor might also be taking care for us. Do you have the sample code of that? If yes, can you share the code here?

Comment: Yes it might not be a perfect solution but We strictly wanted to control the next state in our code so we decided to update the state in code after the user response and also we don't want to loose the out-of-box features.. But for your case, you can check the Sitecore.Kernel for the classes & logic used in the out-of-box workflow.. l

Comment: @Gobinath If I understand correctly, you told you guys have used a pop up and not dialog form right?

Comment: Something like this, 
public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs workflowActionArgument)
{
   Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "DialogProcessor");
}
private void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs clientPipelineArgument)
{
   if (clientPipelineArgument.IsPostBack)
   { Read the response of your dialog box and handle here }
   else
   { SheerResponse.Input(pass required details based on your need) }
} I guess it is worth analyzing the Out-of box workflow code and implement your requirements..

Comment: I did look into it and found that Sitecore uses ContentEditor.aspx pages where we use SheerUI, so that is why I had to start my research from scratch. Do you know a way to pull the response from the Dialog Form i.e. the dialog value?

Comment: Something like this, private void DialogProcessor(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
                if (args.IsPostBack)
                {
                    if (args.HasResult)
                    {
                      string val = args.Result;
                    }
                    SheerResponse.Eval("window.location.reload();");
                }
                else
                {
                    SheerResponse.Input();
                    args.WaitForPostBack();
                }
        }

Comment: I was able to implement the solution without using the processor, but I have a problem where the page doesn't reflect the state until I explicitly hit refresh and go to the item. How did you solve that issue? I saw that you have used the page refresh but in my case, it won't work as the content author is forced to reopen the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, Gobinath I was able to implement the solution based on your sample code and I am adding the code for missing pieces like below

1. How to refresh the Sitecore item on ContentEditor without having to
   refresh the browser.
2. Having a new field to preserve the out of the box next state feature, I added a new field to the new template
   which inherited the Action template.

   ```
           public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
           {
               Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)args, nameof(args));
               Item workflowItem = args.DataItem;

               string nextStateId = args.CommandItem.Fields["Authentication Next State"]?.GetValue(true);

               NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
              //Add paramters here if needed any

               Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", new ClientPipelineArgs() { Parameters = parameters });
           }

           private void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
           {
               if (args.IsPostBack)
               {
                   if (args.HasResult)
                   {
                       string isUserAuthenticated = args.Result?.ToLower();

                       if (isUserAuthenticated == "true")
                       {
                           string itemId = args.Parameters["workflowItemId"];
                           string nextStateId = args.Parameters["nextStateId"];

                           Item item = Global.ContentDatabase.GetItem(itemId);
                           string workflowNextState = Global.ContentDatabase.GetItem(nextStateId)?.DisplayName;

                           if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(workflowNextState))
                           {

                               WorkflowResult result = ChangeWorkflowState(item, workflowNextState);

                               if (result.Succeeded)
                               {
                                   string itemLang = args.Parameters["workflowItemLanguage"];
                                   string itemVersion = args.Parameters["workflowItemVersion"];

                                   //Refresh the item on content editor
                                   string load = $"item:load(id={itemId},language={itemLang},version={itemVersion})";
                                   Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer(load, 0);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                                   SheerResponse.Alert(result.Message);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   string controlUri = UIUtil.GetUri("control:AuthenticationDialog");

                   SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(controlUri, true);
                   args.WaitForPostBack();
               }
           }
   ```

To set the result from the Modal

```
SheerResponse.SetDialogValue("add the result");
```

Comment: That's great.. :)